# Custom PHP code to deal with WPform field input

Tags: php, wordpress

I got a WPform on a page on my WordPress site.

Am trying to work out a PHP code that will fetch field input after user press submit button and compare with list of arrays and will redirect to a specific page accordingly if it matches with a specific array else display "wrong input message".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, people on SO will help you better if you show some code, effort or things you tried in your question, not only "what you want to acomplish".

If you want to retrieve the content of your `WPForm`, you should add a 'action' in your 'functions.php' file in Wordpress. This way, PHP will capture the 'submit action' and you could do whatever you want (validate the form inputs, etc.) and decide if finally you submit the form or return an error to the user.

This will be a sample code, in your `functions.php` file:

```
//Capture the wpform submit, and call the "processForm" function
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', 'processForm', 5, 4 );

function processForm( $form_fields, $entry, $form_data, $entry_id ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $form_id = $form_data['id'];
    //$form_data contains the user inputs
    //here you could validate your form

}
```

Try reading the documentation to know more about how to do it: https://wpforms.com/docs/

Comment: My bad...
Thats what i basically needed .Asap
Thanks

Comment: No worries, you will learn by using S.O. If the answer solved your problem, mark as resolved to help others too. Thanks and welcome!